# how to grep multiple matches one line?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

For example：

`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame ;
- (NSUInteger)hideAllHUDsForView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated ;
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context ;`

I want to get the param eg: `frame` `view` `animated` `keyPath`..., the param between `)` and a blank, how to do with grep on shell?

Comment: There are many `)`s. How do you know which one you want to find? What's the pattern?

Comment: `grep -E "frame|animated|view|keyPath" someFile` maybe?

Comment: That's what I want to ask. I wrote this `egrep -o ').* ' filename`, but it matched the whole line.

Comment: @Mark Setchell , It's not constant, there are much more lines like the three.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your rule is, but how about this?

```
sed 's/[^ ]*://g;s/([^()]*)//g;s/;$//' filename
```

Roughly translated, that's "get rid of anything ending with a colon, then parentheses (and the things inside them), then the trailing semicolon".